# Detect pause in SerialPort input

Tags: c#, serial-port, naudio

In my application, any phone can voice-connect to my 3G USB modem and the call gets picked up immediately. It receives audio as PCM (8000 samples, 16 bits, mono) through a serial port and uses Microsoft's Speech Synthesizer to talk back to the caller.

The problem is, the application should talk back only when the caller has stopped speaking. How can I detect that ?

I tried implementing a 3-second timer which resets itself when data is received from the serial port, so when the timer gets 'ticked' it should mean that that the caller was silent for 3 seconds. But it doesn't work that way. What did I do wrong ?

```
private void DataRecdFromSerial(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
     say.Stop(); say.Start(); // reset timer with interval 5000
     int n = usb.BytesToRead;
     byte[] comBuffer = new byte[90000];
     usb.Read(comBuffer, 0, n);
     if(comBuffer.Length > 0)
     {  
          wfw.Write(comBuffer, 0, n); // NAudio Wave File Writer
     }
}

private void say_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Caller stopped speaking for 5 seconds (not working)
 }
```

Comment: You need to do a better job of analyzing why your timer scheme "doesn't work".

Comment: The timer event was not firing due to having been called in a [different thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what magic on earth should data flow interrupt when there is silence ? you will get a continuous stream as long as the line is connected that is the most logical of all software and electronical engineering implementation that one can excpect today. So you need to analyze the spectrum of the sound wave and calculate root mean square amplitude to get energy. you compare to a threshold that you fix by empirical testing (because silence is actually a small noise that you need to accept).

Comment: I totally agree with you, but to be fair some VOIP protocols don't send any data over the wire during silence, instead depending on a 2nd channel to signal (like SIP) the differentiate between prolonged silence and a terminated call.

Comment: Ah, actually I half-suspected that but hid the thought under my mental carpet. Because we all have noticed on cell phones or other less traditional phones (skype etc) that relative silence often cut weirdly to full silence when no one talks. But it could also be the anti-echo system that tries to make the line uni-directional (a pain for the speakers, often). Now, in Aniruddha's case, is it a voip system ? maybe he could use that property if yes, otherwise RMS integration.

Comment: No it's not voip but the synthesizer itself in conjunction with timeout properties can detect a pause, so problem solved. I've still gotten into audio processing for a greater degree of control though.